# How to set the color of function input parameter in visual studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, fonts

I want to change the color of `aabbcc`:

```
class ABC
{
    void test(int aabbcc);
};
```

The color of `aabbcc` should be changed by "Tool -> Option -> Fonts and Colors -> C++ Parameters", but it has no effect of parameters of function declaration, which means:

1.Does NOT work:

```
class ABC
{
    void test(int aabbcc); // aabbcc is black color
};
```

2.Works:

```
// in .cpp file
void ABC::test(int aabbcc) // aabbcc is in correct color
{
    // ...
}
```

or

```
// in .h file
class ABC
{
    void test(int aabbcc) // aabbcc is in correct color
    {
    }
};
```

Which means, `aabbcc` is only in correct color if the full function body appears.
Why is it? Is it a bug or I missed something?
Thanks!

Comment: Your curious is amazing! I never thought about that..

Comment: I thought the most amazing part is that visual studio give the same thing by different definitions!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Great...I found answer on my own again...

Set "Tool -> Option -> Fonts and Colors -> Identifier"

But I do not understand why, lol.

Comment: Could down-voter give a reason please? Is this solution not working?